# Flutter Regex white space and title case

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I'm trying to remove trailing and leading white spaces from an input field so I can store user names in Firebase in a uniform format, i.e. "Mary Jane " or " Mary Jane " to "Mary Jane".

This is as far as I could get but it removes all white spaces i.e. "MaryJane"

```dart
TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
      new RegExp(r"\s\b|\b\s"),
  ),
],
```

I am also trying to find a way to capitalise first letters of a string i.e. "mary jane" to "Mary Jane"

Comment: It should be `new RegExp(r"^\s|\s$")`

Comment: The problem is it's not allowing me to add a white space, for example if a user's name is "Van Bommel"

Answer (score 1):

Handle removing leading & trailing white spaces on TextField `onEditingComplete` property

```
 onEditingComplete : () {
   print(firstName.text.trim());
 },
```

or on the form submit

```
ElevatedButton(
  child: const Text('Submit'),
  onPressed: () {
    print(firstName.text.trim());
  },
),
```

On Capitalising the letters[**words**] , you may use TextField `textCapitalization` property

```
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
```

**Gist:** Complete code **[here](https://gist.github.com/SteplerPaulo/5d61c99a8330eaf5ff86709c8b2ddfb3)**. You may copy & paste it on **[dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/)** to see the result

Comment: thanks, your suggestion worked